Reload Web-Serverless PHP.ini
I've added sqlsrv.dll for my windows php install, but it doesn't seem to recognize it. It's not running on a server, just the cli on my local machine.
It gives me this error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64 (The specified module could not be found),C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 But it's in the correct directory?

I tried all the solutions offered in similar questions to no avail.

Realized this version of srvsql is wayyy outdated. Got the up to date dll (pdo_sqlsrv_83_nts_x64.dll) and it fixed everything.
